Bayesian VAR in-sample h-days ahead forecasts
Referring to Afonso et al. (2023) “Scarce, Abundant, or Ample?
A Time-Varying Model of the
Reserve Demand Curve”. I have come across a confusing statement.link to the paper
Referring to Equation 9 in page 33, it says

where T1, T2, and T3 represent 2010-2014, 2015-3/09/2020, and 3/16/2020-12/29/2021; i=
1,...,N are draws from the in-sample five-day-ahead joint posterior distribution of the
federal funds-IORB spread (p) and normalized reserves (q) from our bivariate time-varying
VAR model (6).22 We generate these forecasts every five days and set N = 100. To improve
eﬃciency and reliability, we also provide the optimization algorithm with the analytical
gradient of the objective function.

What do they mean by in-sample 5 days ahead forecasts ?
If I use information up to time (t) to forecast the next 5 days, isn’t that the definition of OOS forecasts?
